# Can I use multiple Twitter accounts on Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, twitter

I'd like to know if I can switch between multiple Twitter accounts using Safari? (Like on iOS.)

Comment: Short answer, no. (But there is a fast way by storing your login information on keychain)

Answer (score 2):

On Safari, or any other browser that supports `private/incognito mode`, you could start a new `private/incognito` window by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> `File | New Private/Incognito Window` and enter different credentials.

Every new window will store account information isolated, and will be deleted once you close the window.

Answer (score 0):

Not on safari, only on chrome or firefox with cookie swapping add ons:

Chrome : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swap-my-cookies/dffhipnliikkblkhpjapbecpmoilcama

Mozilla : https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/cookieswap/

You could just use keychain to store passwords and logout/ login quickly or you could also something like tweetdeck or other third party apps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you are saying as like iOS you mean the Twitter App for iOS? If so then what you need is the Twitter App for Mac that is available for free in the Mac App Store [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/twitter/id409789998?mt=12). It does allow to add more than one accounts.